# Space separated multiple inputs on single line

Tags: c++

```
5 1256 4323 7687 3244 5678
2 2334 7687
5 2334 5678 6547 9766 9543
```

I am supposed to input in the above form. The first integer in each line decides the number of integers that follow. Since the first integer can vary, I do not know if it is possible with 'scanf'.

Comment: `scanf` is a C function - if this is a C++ program then you probably want to use C++ I/O idioms.

Comment: why you wanna use `scanf` rather than `std::cin`?

Comment: I am not confined to 'scanf'. I mentioned it since I used it for whitespace separated input. But here since the number of inputs in each line vary, I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you can do it with `scanf` as follows.

```
while (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
  row++;
  for (col = 0; col < n; col++)
    scanf("%d", &a[row][col]);
}
```

It's much the same with `cin`:

```
while (cin >> n) {
  row++;
  for (col = 0; col < n; col++)
    cin >> a[row][col];
}
```

---

A more concrete example, suppose the input is maximum `N` lines.

```
int** a = new int*[N];
int row = -1; // not started yet
while (cin >> n) {
  row++;
  a[row] = new int[n];
  for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
    cin >> a[row][col];
}
```

If `N` is not known in advance, we can also make use of `std::vector` as follows.

```
vector<vector<int> > a;
while (cin >> n) {
  vector<int> line(n);
  for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
    cin >> line[col];
  a.push_back(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
Where to initialize 'row'?
Will the 'cin' form take whitespace separated input?

Comment: @HarishVishwakarma Of course. `cin` takes inputs separated by whitespaces, including end of lines.

Comment: @HarishVishwakarma Also I updated my answer with a more concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

I will never get why you dont want to search on Stackoverflow.com! It was answered many times. For example -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
std::ifstream  data("test.txt");

std::string line;
while(std::getline(data,line))
{
    std::stringstream  lineStream(line);
    std::string        cell;
    while(std::getline(lineStream,cell,' '))
    {
        std::cout<<cell<<std::endl;

    }
  }
}
```